# Sigmoid always returns 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, regression, sigmoid

Consider the following:

```
def sigmoid(inSig):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-inSig))

def classifyVector(inX, weights):
    prob = sigmoid(sum(inX*weights))
    if prob > 0.5: return 1.0
    else: return 0.0
```

My understanding is that the sigmoid result ranges from 0 to 1.  According to this post (http://clear-lines.com/blog/post/Logistic-Regression.aspx):

*"A positive value will return a value greater than 0.5, and the greater the input value, the closer to 1. One could think of the function as returning a probability: for very high or low values of x, there is a high certainty that it belongs to one of the two groups, and for values close to zero, the probability of each group is 50% / 50%."*

But, the sigmoid seems to only produce a 0.5 (i.e., a zero classification) if it is Sigmoid(0).  Unless inX or weights is zero (or zero vector), won't classifyVector always return a 1?

For example, consider the following data:

```
trainset = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]])
trainlbl = np.array([1,12,11,40])
```

Here, the inX will never be zero.  If one works out the math, the weights will not be zero, either.  So, how can the sigmoid provide a fair analysis?

Comment: Probably replace the 1 in l. 2 wih a 1.0? As far as I remember Python this might change the whole type of the devision. [Is this for a neural net?]

Comment: Why is the param called inSig and the var inX?

Comment: I edited it.  It's for a logistic regression.

Comment: Tried changing the 1 to a 1.0? This might not help, but maybe it does....

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't change anything - I think the 1.0 in the numerator already took care of that.

Comment: Okay :/ So - is this for a neural network?

Comment: It's for a logistic regression.  I think I may have found the issue:  my set of labels has to be 0's and 1's for the training to be sensible.

Comment: And, it also seems that making each column in trainset so similar made the results look odd.

Answer (score 0):

> But, the sigmoid seems to only produce a 0.5 (i.e., a zero classification) if it is Sigmoid(0). Unless inX or weights is zero (or zero vector), won't classifyVector always return a 1?

0.5 is a threshold value, not something that one would have to achieve. classifyVector will return 1 iff sigmoid produces **more than** 0.5. There is still a lot of remaining values - everything between 0 and 0.5. You are right that obtaining exactly 0.5 is extremely rare, but this is not a problem, since every value less than 0.5 will result in classification "0". And basically (if you crunch the math) you will get classification 1 iff `inSig` is positive (and 0 if it is negative). Since squashing through sigmoid makes positive values become bigger than 0.5 and negatives less than 0.5 (while, as you stated - zero is transformed to 0.5).

Answer (score 0):

Sigmoid take a real number and make it between 0 and 1

Change your traing labels to something like 0 or 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).